# Everytime I call the setinterval method, my counter accelerates - vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, setinterval, countdown

I am developing a countdown called by a function. The goal is to restart the countdown every time the user answers a question in the game and the next question is instantiated. The problem I've been facing is that every time I call the function before time runs out, the next countdown gets accelerated and skips numbers.

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ countDown }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      countDown: 10,
    };
  },
  method: {
    countDownTimer() {
      const timer = setInterval(() => {
        if (this.countDown > 0) {
          this.countDown--;
        } else {
          clearInterval(timer);
        }
      }, 1000);
    },
    nextquestion(){
      this.countDownTimer();
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.countDownTimer();
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Well yes. If you run a second timer, then you have two things decrementing the timer every ~second. You haven't done anything to stop the previous timer.

Comment: Okay, so how can i stop and reset the previous timer?

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of research and trying, I was able to solve this with a few changes:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ countDown }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      countDown: 10,
    };
  },
  created(){
  this.timer = 0;
  },
  method: {
    countDownTimer() {
      clearInterval(this.timer);
      this.timer = setInterval(() => {
        if (this.countDown > 0) {
          this.countDown--;
        } else {
          clearInterval(this.timer);
        }
      }, 1000);
    },
    nextquestion(){
      this.countDown = 10;
      this.countDownTimer();
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.countDownTimer();
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: I would move `clearInterval(this.timer)` from `nextquestion` to the beginning of `countDownTimer`. Because `countDownTimer` should never create an additional timer, so you should ensure that in that function itself.

Comment: Great suggestion! I revised my answer, thank you!

Comment: This is why research is suggested before you post a question

Comment: Yesterday I spent all day looking through other questions and videos for a way to solve this problem. None of them actually prevented the time from speeding up. Just take a look at the other questions on this topic here on the stack overflow, especially the ones involving vue.js.